# Access Postgres table data files in RDS Aurora Postgres

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I would like to find the date for the most latest changes on a postgres table . I see understand that we can get this info from accessing table data files. But my postgres database is hosted as AWS RDS aurora (Postgres database engine) . I guess we cant access the internals of RDS , how do i get this info , any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

That is futile, even if you could get the files from Amazon, which you cannot.

The data files are also modified if no DML operation is going on: both autovacuum and HOT chain pruning would do that.

Comment: so my understanding, we cant access the table datafiles and even if we get it , we can exactly find the last modified data (as in like DML statements on a particular table). and to finally conclude : we cant get the last modified information of a table from AWS RDS aurora Postgres DB right ?

Comment: Yes. PostgreSQL doesn't track that information at all.